# select record based on the max value of max occurances and username

Tags: mysql

The following query works ok:

```
SELECT user.username, preference.user_id, preference.category,COUNT(*) AS occurrences 
  FROM preference inner 
  JOIN user on preference.user_id=user.userid
 where category is not null and category!=""
 GROUP BY category,user_id 
 ORDER BY occurrences DESC ;
```

[fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba4ba7/1/0)

I would just like

A)To get only the most popular category for each username (The one that has the max occurrences) so for the fiddle above for user1 it would be Clothing, Shoes & Accessories (3 occurrences) and for user2 Antiques (3 occurrences), all the other rows in the example apart from those two should be omitted.

B)Another query to get the second most popular category for each username

Comment: there are multiple usernames coming back from the query, this will just return the first username on the list with the max occurrences but we would loose all the info for all the other usernames..

Comment: From which table does the `category` column come?  Also, you are misusing the pernicious GROUP BY extension in MySQL, so your query is returning some randomly chosen username. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: preference table, I have updated the question, existing query is working as expected apart from the additional functionality required as explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables to only select the 2 most popular categories per user

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * ,
    @rowNum := IF(@prevUserId = user_id,@rowNum+1,1) rowNum,
    @prevUserId := user_id
    FROM (
        SELECT user.username,@prevUserId,preference.user_id, category, COUNT(*) AS occurrences
        FROM preference inner JOIN user 
        on preference.user_id=user.userid
        where category is not null and category!=""
        GROUP BY category,preference.user_id
    ) t1 order by user_id, occurrences desc
) t1 WHERE rowNum <= 2
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba4ba7/24

Comment: You don't need the cross join, your `IF` handles `@prevUserId` being `NULL`and sets the `@rowNum` correctly.

Comment: thanks for the answer but this still returns all the categories per user some of them having a row number of 1 and 2.

Comment: @Athanatos can you post a fiddle that reproduces the problem?